# Parsley data-parsley-trigger-after-failure NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, taglib, parsley.js, parsley, jquery-form-validator

After fist form validation, parsley lists all the not valid fields. It ,then, fires validation process on keyup of each failed field.

For a better user Xperience, it would be better to change this behaviour and set it to form submit or even focusOut on field.

For this, parsley introduced the `data-parsley-trigger-after-failure` option

but in my example, this is not working. is there an option that should be added too.

Comment: Not working how? Do you have a live example?

Comment: Please post your code